# Time in gtalk and facebook chat is wrong

Tags: browser, time

I messed with some time zone settings while installing Redis yesterday following this tutorial:
http://www.codingsteps.com/install-redis-2-6-on-ubuntu/

(at least I think this is when the problem started). Right now the clock in Ubuntu shows the right time, but when I use Gtalk or Facebook to chat, wrong timestaps are added, the time shown is 8:09AM instead of 1:09PM.

I'm on Central European Time, I use Firefox browser. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the content of file /etc/timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by trying:

```
tzselect
```

and selecting my locale, then:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Belgrade /etc/localtime
```

and then another thing that I can't remember for the life of me... In any case, it worked AFTER restarting my PC.

I think any of these will do the trick on their own, it's just that you need torestart you computer after setting it.